# Should I disable the root account on my Debian PC for security?

Tags: debian, security, root

From a security standpoint should I disable the root account for my personal computer running Debian 9.1?

And if so: what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: There is no way to disable the root account. An account with number 0 (and usually called root) **must** always exist. What could be done, and is done in Ubuntu (and some other distros) is remove the root account password. So, no login to root could be succesful, no ssh could log in as root, no matter how hard it try, only by using sudo could an user raise its privileges to root. Should you do it? Sure, why not?. Is it more secure? Yes, a little (as long as no user is running shells as root for a long time).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are different reasons to disable root account, for example:

1. Your system is available on a network and you want to protect yourself against brute force attacks, so no one can guess your root account password.
2. Developers wants to stop the users from running a command like `su -` to get a full root shell, because it's now a lot easier to do something wrong which causes damage to the system. however they can still use something like `sudo -i`, `sudo -s`, `sudo /bin/some-shell` or even `sudo su -` if they are in sudoers file

   The idea is to force the user to use the `sudo` instead of sharing a single root password between all users and using the `sudo` comes with some advantages, for example:

   - It's less likely for you to leave an open shell with complete root access, `sudo` permissions expires after a while.
   - You can define more flexible ruels using `sudoers` file
   - It logs who is doing what, etc.
   - Read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for more info.

---

To disable, you can remove the password of the account or lock it down, or even do both of them:

1. Remove the root password:

   ```
   sudo passwd -d root
   ```
2. Lock the account:

   ```
   sudo passwd -l root
   ```

Comment: Am I mistaken that `passwd -d root` should allow becoming `root` without even a password prompt challenge and `passwd -l root` is a must to deny this?

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong, you can't login into a account when it doesn't have any password, check it yourself... also you can' unlock a locked account if it doesn't have any password too.

Comment: I locked the root account. Now I have the problem that I can't de/install packages via Apper anymore as I get an "Authentication failure" when I enter my root password when it asks for it. It only works if I start apper as root via `sudo apper`. But if I do that apper looks strange and old (e.g. no icons) and I get a number of errors in the console. Is this normal? How can I keep using apper to install and deinstall software while at the same time locking the root account login?

Comment: As I said before, we use `sudo` instead of root account directly, so what you are doing (using `sudo`) is the correct way to do it. why you are getting an ugly look? I guess it's because you are running the `apper` using `sudo` (root user) and your root user doesn't have a proper theme/icon selected. you can install `lxappearance` then run it using `sudo lxappearance` select a theme  and Icon then you should be fine.

Comment: @Ravexina Didn't notice you commented and now [I've put up a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383444/apper-errors-and-looking-strange-when-opening-it-via-sudo) with all the errors I get. I don't have `lxappearance` in KDE but maybe there's an equivalent for KDE.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm I'm not really a KDE folk (never used it more than of an hour). however this kind of errors are mostly normal when you run  a command in a terminal.

Comment: `sudo passwd -l root` will still allow the user to authenticate with an SSH key. See https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/ssh-public-key-authentication-still-works-for-locked-user-4175424034/#post5964173.

Comment: To note for future visitors: `sudo passwd -d root` _will allow you to log in as root without a password_ (tested on a Debian system). `sudo passwd -l root` is the command which actually blocks the login (by corrupting the hashed value by adding a `!` to the front). While you _can_ run both commands in the order shown here, it's probably better to only run the `-l` version (avoids small window where anybody could log in, and the old password can be recovered if you change your mind later with `-u`, which removes the `!`).